# correctly resize paper.js after css class change

Tags: javascript, css, paperjs

I have several canvases and paperScopes, and I switch between them by "minimizing" and "restoring" them by adding\removing a collapse class, to their parent div.

The problem is, that once I setup paper to a canvas, it retains the canvas' original size after it gets resized by removing the minimization.

I've tried adding `data-paper-resize="true"` or `resize="true"` to the canvas, but that didn't work.

I've tried dispatching a resize event with `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));` but it seems to conflict with paper and throw an exception (filed a bug for that).

Resizing the window gets paper to the correct state.

Here's a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/o2fnarqx/3/

Any ideas on how to make it resize correctly?

I'm also open to suggestions with regards to other drawing libraries as well... All I need to do is display different images on the different minimize-able canvases, and draw interactive markers on top of these images (the markers need to get transparent on mouse hover, and get dragged on mouse drag).

And I work in pure JS, no Node.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the canvas size manually every time its size change, using the [view.viewSize](http://paperjs.org/reference/view/#viewsize) property.
In order to do that, you can use this code:

```
yourPaperScope.view.viewSize = new Size(yourCanvas.offsetWidth, yourCanvas.offsetHeight);
```

Hopefully, this will be enough for you to adapt it to your specific case.